# Invalid dex file indices, expecting file 'classes٢.dex' but found 'classes2.dex'. (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, dex

## **Error:**

```
  Invalid dex file indices, expecting file 'classes٢.dex' but found 'classes2.dex'.
```

How do I solve this big problem ?

The error appears on my second project as well

## `build.gradle(:app)` file :

`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    //configurations.all {
    //    resolutionStrategy {
    //        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    //    }}
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "********"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }


}

dependencies {
    api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-beta01'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.6'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    def lottieVersion = "3.4.0"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"


    implementation 'com.scwang.wave:MultiWaveHeader:1.0.0-alpha-1'
    implementation 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.mergehez:ArgPlayer:v2.1'
    implementation 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.6'

    implementation 'com.github.recruit-lifestyle:PlayPauseButton:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.claucookie.miniequalizer:library:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.github.alxrm:youtube-play-icon:0.9'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.cloudinary:cloudinary-android:1.30.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.7.0') { exclude module: 'glide' }
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:4.8.9'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:21.3.0'
    implementation project(':nativetemplates')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.kenilt.loopingviewpager:loopingviewpager:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0'
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:3.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`

## The language of the device is Arabic. When I change the language to English, the error disappears

## But I don't want to change it to English

## I tried to change the language of the numbers to English, and it did not work, and I returned it to Arabic, and it did not work

Comment: Try cleaning project and build again

Comment: @khalid-taha I tried

Comment: حاولت ياخالد ما ظبط ، بس جربت غيرت هذه multiDexEnabled fasle الى true  ثانية وطلع اخطاء وحليتها وان شاء الله يظبط

Comment: ماظبطت طريقتي 

Comment: contact me on gmail: kha.taha92 at gmail dot com, sorry but can't littrally write my exact email